# Map x, y coordinates to 2d array indicess

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to map x, y coordinates of a Swing GUI to the certain row/column it represents. Depending on where I click within each "square" it will toggle either the line to appear above, below, to the left or to the right. For example, if my mouse is in the top half of the square it can either toggle the top, left or right line to appear. Likewise for the bottom half except the bottom line instead of the top. To differentiate whether it's a right line or left line to appear it depends on what vertical half of the square the mouse is in.

[image: Reference picture]

On top of this, if the button at the top screen is interacted with, the program should print "Button clicked". The "button" is simply drawn as a rectangle and no JButton or anything is used as it had to be created using simple rectangle and text.

The code I currently have is this, which draws the necessary balls and also the line between them. For example if the mouse is clicked at the top of the grey grid shown in the image above it will call drawHorizontalLine with r = 0 and c = 0. For the square next to it, and the mouse is closest to the top line it will call with r = 0 and c = 1. If it was a vertical line to be drawn such as the very top left it would be r = 0, c = 0 and so on. R representing rows, and C representing columns.

If you need any further info, please let me know in the comments.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class SwingMain extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        final static int SEPARATION = 125;
        final static int DIAMETER = 15;
        final static int NBALLS = 5;
        final static int WIDTH = (NBALLS) * (SEPARATION + DIAMETER) + (SEPARATION);
        final static int HEIGHT = (NBALLS) * (SEPARATION + DIAMETER) + (SEPARATION);
        final static int XSTART = SEPARATION;
        final static int YSTART = SEPARATION;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SwingMain().start());
        }

        public void start() {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            frame.add(this);
            setBackground(Color.gray);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);

            int y = YSTART;
            for (int r = 0; r < NBALLS; r++) {
                int x = XSTART;
                for (int c = 0; c < NBALLS; c++) {
                    g2d.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
                    x += SEPARATION + DIAMETER;;
                }
                y += SEPARATION + DIAMETER;;
            }

            drawHorizontalLine(g2d, 0, 0);
            drawButton(g2d);
        }

        public void drawHorizontalLine(Graphics2D g, int r, int c) {
            int x1 = (SEPARATION) * (c + 1);
            int x2 = x1 + SEPARATION;
            int y1 = (SEPARATION) * (r + 1) + 2;
            int y2 = SEPARATION * (r + 1) + 6;
            drawRectangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, Color.WHITE);
        }

        public void drawRectangle(Graphics2D graphic, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color c) {
            graphic.fillRect(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2), Math.abs(x1 - x2), Math.abs(y1 - y2));
        }

        private void drawButton(Graphics2D g) {
            int centerX = WIDTH / 2;
            int x1 = centerX - 100;
            int x2 = centerX + 100;
            int y1 = 25;
            int y2 = 75;
            drawRectangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, Color.WHITE);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
            int strWidth = fm.stringWidth("Completed.");
            int strHeight = fm.getAscent();
            g.drawString("Completed.",
                      (centerX - 20) - strWidth / 2,
                      45 + strHeight);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            //If the area of the button is clicked
            System.out.println("Button clicked.");
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    }
```

Comment: Well, its not worth me helping again since you still don't understand the suggestions I provided in your last question and you haven't implement those suggestions properly. If you don't understand the basic math from those suggestions then you won't be able to do proper hit detection to determine where in the rectangle you have clicked. 1) the "width" calculation is wrong. 2) the "height" should be the same as the width. So it is also wrong. 3) You increment the "x/y" values incorrectly.

Comment: 4) Your drawHorizontalLine() method is overly complicated, if not compleletely wrong. It appear you don't understand how the Graphics.drawRect(...) method work. The method needs the x/y values and the width/height. I have no idea why you have all those variable and use the Math.min() and Math.abs() methods. All you need to calculate the x/y values based on the row column. Then the width/height will always be constant since the space between the balls and constant and the height of the line is constant.

Comment: Once again I would say you haven't drawn your layout on a piece of paper. Start with the base case of 2 balls. To make sure everything is centered the width (and height) should be: separator + diameter + separator + diameter + separator. Does this not make sense as you can see that each ball has the same space before/after it is drawn. So using your numbers the width (and height) should be: 125 + 15 + 125 + 15 + 125 = 405. Is this what you get when you use your formula?

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I have two separate working packages for this problem, one which I use for any questions which has most of the code removed to keep it concise and relevant to the question I ask. I have edited the OP to have what I considered to be the correct height/width, correct me if I am still wrong. The drawHorizontalLine can be ignored tbh, it doesn't have to do with the question I am asking. The drawRectangle was a method I was given that I had to use so I'm working wtih it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again you just have a basic math problem to solve.

> Depending on where I click within each "square" it will toggle either the line to appear above, below, to the left or to the right...

Well, I don't really understand your full requirement, but it's not important that I do. Because this just boils down to a math formula again. So it is up to you to implement the formula based you your requirements.

Maybe the following pointers will get you started in the right direction.

Maybe you can introduce the concept of a "cell". In your example you have 5 balls so you have 4 square cells on each row/column.

Now we can define the "cell size (both width/height) to be:

```
int cellSize = DIAMETER + SEPARATION;
```

Now in the mouse listener you need to determine:

1. which cell you clicked in
2. which side of the cell you clicked in (left or right)

So, if we start with the column first (the logic for the row will be similar) you might do something like:

```
int columnPoint = event.getX() - SEPARATION; 

if (columnPoint < 0 ) // you clicked in the left margin

int columnCell = columnPoint / cellSize;

If (columnCell > NBALLS) // you clicked in the right margin

int cellPoint = columnPoint % cellSize);

if (cellPoint < cellSize / 2)
    // you clicked on the left half
else
    // you clicked on the right half
```

Repeat the above basic logic to determine the row that was clicked and whether you clicked in the top/bottom.

Again, none of the code is tested. It is the concept I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks, I done it quite similarly too where I pretty much divided it by the squares that the 4 dots surround and finding the closest border from a square.